# Reverse many of the changes, including ... . What does including refer to?

Tags: clauses

There is a sentence:

> Kılıçdaroğlu and his opposition coalition campaigned on the promise of returning Turkey to parliamentary democracy, overhauling two decades of Erdoğan’s rule by pledging to reverse many of the changes that have marked his leadership, including concentrating power around his office and jailing opponents.

So,which does the author want to express:

1. Reverse many of the changes, and the many (of the changes) is including concentrating power around his office and jailing opponents;
2. Reverse many of the changes, and will including concentrating power around his office and jailing opponents to reverse many of the changes.

Which is right? Why?

Thansk.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly means 1.
Concentration of power around the president's office, and jailing the president's  opponents are two things that are contrary to parliamentary democracy. The opposition to Erdogan wants to reverse those things.

Comment: Can means 1 be fixed by the structure of the sencente?

Comment: The reference of "including concentrating power around his office and jailing opponents" is the word "changes", which is what the opposition candidate proposes to reverse. That is the most recent possible reference in the sentence. That closeness is a structural reason to attach it there. There is also the question of a coherent meaning for the sentence - jailing one's opponents and concentrating executive power are not consistent with parliamentary democracy, which is what the candidate wants to support.